# How to enable, disable buttons depending on the text clicked?

Tags: angular, dom

I am displaying integers which are mapped to boolean datatypes. I created a click function, which change a local variable, which I use to property-bind it with the disabled-property of a button. It does work. If the value is false every button is disabled, true and every button is enabled, but I want to disable AND enable button depending on the integer.

I need to change the click function and maybe the mapping but I do not know exactly what to do..

In the app.component.html I have following code:

```
<p *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="buttonStatus(item)">
  {{ statusMap[item.status] }} </p>
<button [disabled]="!isValid">Button1</button>
<button [disabled]="!isValid">Button2</button>
<button [disabled]="!isValid">Button3</button>
```

In the app.component.ts:

```
statusMap = {
  1: false,
  2: true,
  3: false
};

items = [{
  status: 1
}, {
  status: 2
}, {
  status: 3
}];

isValid = false;
buttonStatus(item) {
  this.isValid = this.statusMap[item.status];
}
```

So every button is either disabled or enabled, but I want to have some enabled and disabled depending on the integer of item.status. For example:
Clicking on item with the status 1, the first and the third button should be disabled BUT the second should stay enabled.

I appreciate your help! Sorry I had to display "In the app.component.html I have following code:" and "In the app.component.ts" because of the new structure on this forum.

Comment: One thing is ambiguous, if 'disabled' is depending on the status integer, clicking on the item or not is irrelevant. Please clarify your requirement here.

Comment: yes, that's true, the click on buttons is not doing anything. i do not know what was the real intention behind it.

Comment: @wannadream  Later on the the buttons will do something but it depends on the status whether a button can be clicked or not. I try to simulate it. Now there is no action

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `isValid` for enabling  and disabling the different buttons. If `isValid` is true, it will enable all buttons as per your template code.
 You should be having a function call from your button for checking status.

```
<p *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="buttonStatus(item)">
  {{ statusMap[item.status] }} </p>
<button [disabled]="checkStatus('1')">Button1</button>
<button [disabled]="checkStatus('2')">Button2</button>
<button [disabled]="checkStatus('3')">Button3</button>
```

send your button-id or index to determine if it needs to be enabled or disabled.

have the `checkStatus(id)` function in component to hold the logic to return `true` or `false` based on the id provided. Have your button click set the status as it is doing right now.

```
checkStatus(id): boolean {
  return this.statusMap[id];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I will try to understand your code!

Comment: and since you are not changing status on button click, that click event is not needed really.

Comment: Hm, that is just an example. Later on clicking on a li-tag should check a variable of type integer. Depending on the integer, some button should change, some not. So with this code it won't work.. ~ It really has to be as mentioned. Checking for the value, in this example an integer and then decide which button should be disabled. I want to understand the logic of how to achieve that.

Comment: You get the idea based on what you shared in question. you need to modify the code as per your requirement

Comment: I will try to get the logic! Let it as it be, thank your for the new perspective!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the context of the question completely. However, this may help.

You could use a public property to track which button is selected, then simply check that property in the template for each button, to determine whether it should be enabled. A click handler function can set the property.

```
<p *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="buttonStatus(item)">
    {{ statusMap[item.status] }} </p>
<button [disabled]="{{enabler!=1}}" (click)=clickHandler(1)">Button1</button>
<button [disabled]="{{enabler!=2}}" (click)=clickHandler(2)>Button2</button>
<button [disabled]="{{enabler!=3}}" (click)=clickHandler(3)>Button3</button>

public enabler: int;
public clickHandler(selectedCheckbox: int) {
    enabler = selectedCheckbox;
}
```

Comment: what is `myproperty` doing here? i do not see it used in your code? and the clickHandler is not needed since the question doesn't talk about it.

Comment: This shows an alternative way to handle the setting disabled property, based on somewhat unclear requirements.